# Fetching event data from a Google calendar using FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have been trying to fetch event data from a Google calendar using FullCalendar for hours now. I'd like the data to be in an object so I can use it outside of the full calendar appearing on my page, and I can't seem to get it right.

Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/wrchapin%40gmail.com/public/basic',
    });

    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' );
    console.log(events.length);
});
```

The calendar appears as it should on the page, but the console shows a length of 0. What is going on? Am I using the clientEvents method improperly?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the call to fetch the `clientEvents` happens before the calendar has loaded the events. That's the reason the events array is blank.

You can easily solve this by using the `loading` callback of the calendar. Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/gt8F9/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That is extremely helpful! Now all I have to do is figure out why I can't call clientEvents if the calendar div has its display set to 'none'... Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome! The reason you can't call clientEvents in that case is because FC is coded in such a way that the events get rendered only when the target div is visible. You can overcome this by using `.fullCalendar('render')` explicitly when the div becomes visible. Hope that helps - also, would you mind accepting this as your answer?

Comment: Of course! Although I just realized that clientEvents only returns the events that are displayed on the current month of the calendar. Is there any way to get all events from all months?